# compare 2d array with 1d array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
var player1=["t1", "t9", "t7", "t8", "t2"];
var player2=["t5", "t3", "t4", "t6"];
var winmoves=[[t1,t2,t3],[t4,t5,t6],[t7,t8,t9],[t1,t4,t7],[t2,t5,t8],[t3,t6,t9],[t1,t5,t9],[t3,t5,t7]];

    else if (moves>=3 && moves<=9) {
                    moves+=1;
                    if (turn==1) {
                        var i=0;
                        turn=2;
                        x.innerHTML="<img src='x.png'/>";
                        player1.push(x.id);
                        while(i<=moves){
                            if (winmoves[i] in player1) {
                                alert("player1 wins");
                                document.getElementById("player1").innerHTML=1;
                                }
                            i+=1;
                        }
                    }
```

i have 1d array player1 and 2d array winmoves in javascript and i want to check that w[0]'s all values are present in p and so on for w[1],w[2],etc.
if condition with `(winmoves[i] in player1)` is not working.
i don't know if i am writing this write.
help me guys i am stuck here how can i do so.

It is not working even after i have made these changes.

```
else if (moves>=3 && moves<9) {
                        moves+=1;
                        if (turn==1) {
                            var i=0;
                            turn=2;
                            x.innerHTML="<img src='x.png'/>";
                            player1.push(x.id);
                            while(i<=moves){
                                 mapped1 = winmoves.map(a1 => a1.every(e1 => player1.includes(e1)));
                                if (mapped1[i]) {
                                    alert("player1 wins");
                                    document.getElementById("player1").innerHTML=1;
                                    }
                                i+=1;
                            }
                        }
                        else if (turn==2) {
                            turn=1;
                            var i=0;
                            x.innerHTML="<img src='o.png'/>";
                            turn=1;
                            player2.push(x.id);
                            while(i<=moves)
                            { 
                                 mapped2 = winmoves.map(a => a.every(e => player2.includes(e)));
                                if (mapped2[i]) {
                                    alert("player2 wins");
                                    document.getElementById("player2").innerHTML=1;
                                    }
                                i+=1;
                            }   
                        }

                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply do this with a simple invention of `Array.prototype.intersect()` and the rest is such a straightforward single liner.

```js
Array.prototype.intersect = function(a) {
  return this.filter(e => a.includes(e));
};

var player1 = ["t1","t2","t3","t5","t7"],
   winmoves = [["t1","t2","t3"],["t4","t5","t6"],["t7","t8","t9"],["t1","t4","t7"],["t2","t5","t8"],["t3","t6","t9"],["t1","t5","t9"],["t3","t5","t7"]];
   filtered = winmoves.filter(a => a.intersect(player1).length == a.length);
     mapped = winmoves.map(a => a.intersect(player1).length == a.length);
console.log(filtered);
console.log(mapped);
```

OK we have a generic Array method which finds the intersection of two arrays. (inbetween the array it's called upon and the one provided as argument) It's basically a filter checking each item of first array to see whether it is included in the second array. So we filter out the items exist in both arrays.

To obtain the filtered array we utilize `Array.prototype.filter()` again. This time our first array is `winmoves` which includes arrays that we will check for each the intersection with `player1` array. If the intersection length is equal to `winmove`'s item's length that means all elements of `winmove`'s item is existing in the `player1` array. So we return that array item to the `filtered`.

Specific to your case without using an intersect method you can utilize `Array.prototype.every()` as follows;

```js
var player1 = ["t1","t2","t3","t5","t7"],
   winmoves = [["t1","t2","t3"],["t4","t5","t6"],["t7","t8","t9"],["t1","t4","t7"],["t2","t5","t8"],["t3","t6","t9"],["t1","t5","t9"],["t3","t5","t7"]];
   filtered = winmoves.filter(a => a.every(e => player1.includes(e)));
     mapped = winmoves.map(a => a.every(e => player1.includes(e)));
console.log(filtered);
console.log(mapped);
```

Comment: can u please explain what is happing in this snippet.

Comment: @Rohit Chopra i added an explanation to the answer for your information.

Comment: thanks Redu.. but what if i don't want filtered array. instead of  it  simple true or false.

Comment: @Rohit Chopra just added that to the snippet too. It's just done by replacing filter with map.

Comment: can we do this by using Array.prototype.every()?

Comment: @Rohit Chopra Yes in your particular case in fact you could. Let me improve my answer accordingly.

Comment: @ redu can provide link  for documentation?

Comment: @Rohit Chopra MDN is a perfect resource for JS. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is use nested for loops

```
for(var j = 0, j < elemInP, j++){
    int flag = 0;
    for(var x = 0, x < elemInWx, x++){
        for(var y = 0, y < elemInWy, y++){
            if(p[j] == w[x][y]){
                flag = 1;
                /*There is no need to run this loop once the value has been found*/
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag){
            /*If we have found the value no need to keep looking*/
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!flag){
       print p[j] is not in w;
    }
}
```

This is just a general idea of one way to compare the two arrays. The actual syntax of the code will need to be edited to work in JavaScript as this is just basic pseudocode. Flag is just a variable that holds if the value was found or not and is reset for each new value. For efficiency, you could have a break/return after setting flag = 1, but this is